# Polymorphic association confusion, get resource through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, polymorphic-associations

I might be totally confused and off target here.

I have an Event model, which has_one a Timeline that belongs_to Event. The Timeline has_many TimelineItems that belong_to Timeline.

```
def Event
  has_one :timeline
end

def Timeline
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :timeline_items
end

def TimelineItem
  belongs_to :timeline
end

create_table :admin_timeline_items do |t|
  t.references :admin_timeline
  t.references :user
  t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true
  t.string :method
end
```

So through from a TimelineItem object I would be able to generate for example this output:

> eml created the Post "Hi this is from eml" on [DATE]

The title "Hi this is from eml" would come from the Post object's .title. So eg. this TimelineItem has these settings

```
item.user = User.where(:username => "eml")
item.resource_type = "Post"
item.resource_id = 1
item.created_at = 27/082...13:37
```

So the problem is fetching said Post object, or rather the correct syntax for this particular association. Seems terribly simple to me, but I am not finding the information I need to properly write it.

Thanks for your help & time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry... I was just confusing myself because I had set resource_id in my own test item to a faulty value. My first guess was correct. It is quite simple:

```
class TimelineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timeline
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Access resource like so:

```
TimelineItem.first.resource
=> Post(....)
```